# Lists/DataFrames - Running a function over all values in Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I am stuck at the moment and don't really know how to solve this problem.
I want to apply this calculation to a list/dataframe:

[image: Distance interpolation - inverse distance weighted]

The equation itself is not really the problem for me, I am able to easily solve it manually, but that wouldn't do with the amount of data I have.

- v : value to be approximated
- vi: known values (in my case Temperatures)
- di: distance to the approximated point

So basically this is for calculating/approximating a new temperature value for a position a certain distance away from the corners of the square:

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import math

filepath = r'F:\Data\data.nc' # just the path to the file
obj= xr.open_dataset(filepath)
# This is where I get the coordinates for each of the corners of the square
# from the netcdf4 file

lat = 9.7398
lon = 51.2695
xlat = obj['XLAT'].values
xlon = obj['XLON'].values           
p_1 = [xlat[0,0], xlon[0,0]]
p_2 = [xlat[0,1], xlon[0,1]]
p_3 = [xlat[1,0], xlon[1,0]]
p_4 = [xlat[1,1], xlon[1,1]]

p_rect = [p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4]
p_orig = [lat, lon]

#=================================================
# Calculates the distance between the points
# d = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2))
#=================================================   
distance = []
for coord in p_rect:
    distance.append(math.sqrt(math.pow(coord[0]-p_orig[0],2)+math.pow(coord[1]-p_orig[1],2)))

# to get the values for they key['WS'] for example:
a = obj['WS'].values[:,0,0,0] # Array of floats for the first values
b = obj['WS'].values[:,0,0,1] # Array of floats for the second values
c = obj['WS'].values[:,0,1,0] # Array of floats for the third values
d = obj['WS'].values[:,0,1,1] # Array of floats for the fourth values
```

From then on, I have no idea how I should continue, should I do:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = a
df['b'] = b
df['c'] = c
df['d'] = d
```

Then somehow work with DataFrames, and drop abcd after I got the needed values or should I do it with lists first, then add only the result to the dataframe. I am a bit lost.

The only thing I came up with so far is how it would look like if I would do it manually:

```py
for i starting at 0 and ending if the end of the list [a, b, c d have the same length] is reached .

     1/a[i]^2*distance[0] + 1/b[i]^2*distance[1] + 1/c[i]^2*distance[2] + 1/d[i]^2*distance[3]
v =  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    1/a[i]^2 + 1/b[i]^2 + 1/c[i]^2 + 1/d[i]^2
'''
```

This is the first time I had such a (at least for me) complex calculation on a list/dataframe. I hope you can help me solve this problem or at least nudge me in the right direction.

PS: here is the link to the file:
[LINK TO FILE](https://easyupload.io/75ycey)

Comment: Hmm, you are speaking of xlat and xlon, yet use a standard Euclidian distance. If xlat and xlon are true geographic coordinates, this is wrong...

Comment: Doesn't matter at all, since the distances are too small to matter. The square is 3 km wide, so the effect is negligible.

Comment: If the units are in degrees and except on the equator, it matters. A minute in longitude is exactly a nautical mile anywhere, but a minute in latitude is (almost) 1 nautical mile at the equator, 0,7 nautical miles at 45° and only 0.5 nautical miles at 60°. geopandas exists for a reason...

Comment: Hey, the format uses longitude an latitude in exactly the format I have been using.  
I am not using: 51°15'12.2"N 9°07'22.8"E but 51.253400, 9.123000 for example, in either the input and how I set the area of the square as well. So I am both times in the same format. 
(Geography is not my field of expertise, so thanks for the input)

Comment: At 51 north, you just cannot compute distances that way...

Comment: Why wouldn't I be able to? You are saying this is not possible without explaining yourself or providing backup/sources to your claims. 
I have a coordinate system with those numbers spanning a square, and somewhere in there is, in the same coordinate system a point. I get 4 distances, from each corner of the square and this is what I work with. Nobody has raised any issues so far.

Comment: You are right on one point, it should not matter for the results. Simply a *square* of 1° in both direction is not a square but (close to) a rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply vectorize your calculations. With data frames you can run whole arithmetic operations directly on columns as if they were scalars to generate another column,`df['v']`. Below assumes *distance* is a list of four scalars and remember in Python `^` does not mean power, instead us `**`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd':d})

df['v'] = (1/df['a']**2 * distance[0] +
           1/df['b']**2 * distance[1] + 
           1/df['c']**2 * distance[2] + 
           1/df['d']**2 * distance[3]) / (1/df['a']**2 + 
                                          1/df['b']**2 + 
                                          1/df['c']**2 + 
                                          1/df['d']**2)
```

Or the functional form using Pandas Series [binary operators](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#binary-operator-functions). Below follows the order of operations (Parentheses --> Exponential --> Multiplication/Division --> Addition/Subtraction):

```
df['v'] = (df['a'].pow(2).pow(-1).mul(distance[0]) +
           df['b'].pow(2).pow(-1).mul(distance[1]) + 
           df['c'].pow(2).pow(-1).mul(distance[2]) + 
           df['d'].pow(2).pow(-1).mul(distance[3])) / (df['a'].pow(2).pow(-1) + 
                                                       df['b'].pow(2).pow(-1) + 
                                                       df['c'].pow(2).pow(-1) + 
                                                       df['d'].pow(2).pow(-1))
```

Comment: Oh wow didn't know I could do it like this. This was EXACTLY what I was looking for. I have similiar problems like this as well and now know how to apporach them. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Indeed. Most newcomers believe simple operations require looping across rows but can be handled with pandas/numpy vectorization.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. I am quite new to this, upvoted your post but didn't see the other thing to click at. 
Here, have a thanks in written form as well as a green arrow :).